# Instagram API permission decline

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I have got the access token for the Instagram API but when I try to access the endpoints of tag with this url:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/kuwait/media/recent?access_token=my-access-token*******

It shows:

> {"meta": {"error_type": "OAuthPermissionsException", "code": 400, "error_message": "This request requires scope=public_content, but this access token is not authorized with this scope. The user must re-authorize your application with scope=public_content to be granted this permissions."}}

How do I fix this?

I am not building a full app just wanted to add some features in my project.

Comment: don't post your credentials.

Comment: you can see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38020993/fetching-images-from-a-public-instagram-hashtag/41301176#41301176) and view media with hashtag

Answer (score 3):

your error is You Want to get public_content but your app don't have permission to get public_content.

so solution to your problem is  re-authorize your application with scope=public_content as error describe.

> https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL&response_type=code&scope=basic+public_content+follower_list+comments+relationships+likes

so just add scope=public_content as i suggest

Comment: It still give me results of mine only. I want to get the public data.

Comment: according to this `https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/` you can read any public content, so check whatever you are reading is public or not.

Comment: I have tried hashtags which I never used and it shows me below error:
{"pagination": {"deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"}, "meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}

Comment: you should look at new documentation. `https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/` error you are getting is correct.

Comment: Without all the permission review passed and getting the app reviewed by them. We can't access public data?

Comment: yes you are right. see this >As another example, let's consider an endpoint that returns a list of media: /tags/{tag-name}/media/recent. The response returned by this endpoint will contain only media with the given tag, as expected. But instead of returning media from any public Instagram user, it will return only media that belongs to your sandbox users, restricted to the last 20 for each user.

Comment: This solved it for me but I had to change response_type=code to `token` and used localhost to get the oauth response.  `https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=token&scope=public_content`