# fetching images from a public Instagram hashtag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, instagram, instagram-api

I am developing a website for a couple that are getting married and they created `#somehashtag` where other people can post images to. I want to fetch all images from that hashtag and post it on the site. Nothing works. Ideally I want to use php, but javascript/jquery would do.

What have you tried? The answer is probably everything

- [InstafeedJS](http://pastebin.com/UYmTBnRF) doesn't work, nothing shows
- Old php scripts, even from  2015 posted on SO or elsewhere does not work, nothing works.
- Php libraries are old and unsopported, even the official Ruby and Python libraries!
- Endpoints, require ACCESS-TOKEN and that's well, a very long story:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/somehashtag?access_token=API_CLIENT` and `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/somehashtag?access_token=API_SECRET`

Give:

`{"meta": {"error_type": "OAuthPermissionsException", "code": 400, "error_message": "This client has not been approved to access this resource."}}`

Now trying to generate an access token using third party apps, only generate tokens that can access my account, but the hashtag is not something for me, so the access token will be invalid when fetching hashtags.

Generating tokens using instagram require me asking for permission, as far as I know, correct me if I'm wrong, and if I try to do that I get

[image]

I tried to contact instagram support but they cannot be reached obviously.

Comment: This is most likely not going to work unless you write your own instagram app or you pay for a service that can give you the data you want. Instagram recently changed their terms of service and basically pulled the plug on all the API endpoints where random people could just pull whatever data they wanted.

Comment: @omghai_8782 damn! thanks for letting me know, I wasted more than 3h for nothing :(

Comment: Sorry. If it makes you feel any better, I lost a ton of data to this as well recently... lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this link for view top hashtag

```
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/YOUR_HASHTAG/?__a=1
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want create app which can get hashtag on public mode, first thing you must do is create a submission to instagram. alternative way is, you can try first on sandbox mode. but dont forget to authorize your access token for any scope